# VFP diacritic removal

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro

I am having a problem with a code responsible for removing (replacing) diacritic in a file, using VPF 9.0.

I am using this command for uppercasing and removing the diacritic:
UPPER(CHRTRAN(ALLTRIM(XNAME),"áäÁÄčČďĎéÉíÍĺľĹĽňóôöőÓÔÖŐŕŔšŠťŤúüűÚÜŰýÝžŽ","AAAACCDDEEIILLLLNOOOOOOOORRSSTTUUUUUUYYZZ"))

The problem is that  the first set of characters looks different upon saving. First line is how it should look like, the second is how it actually looks after saving:
"áäÁÄčČďĎéÉíÍĺľĹĽňóôöőÓÔÖŐŕŔšŠťŤúüűÚÜŰýÝžŽ" 
"áäÁÄčEďIéÉíÍĺ_ĹĽňóôöoÓÔÖOŕAšŠťŤúüűÚÜUýÝžÄ"

It removes some of the diacritic marks and I can't make it save in the wanted format.

Would you be able to help me with this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please right click the file in project manager and check 'Code page'? By default it should be windows ANSI (1252) and work right.

Edit: 
To do from command line.

```
MODIFY COMMAND myDiacratics.prg AS 1252
```

when the file comes up, make a change (any change so it would be forced to save) and save. It should save just as you want to.

Comment: Then you can simply use the 'AS nCodePage' parameter of Modify Command. Editing my answer to give a sample.

Comment: Did this work?  Just create a new project and add your program to it.

Comment: Doesn't work. Or at least I did not make it work. The problem is that the whole code (including this part we are discussing) is a part of a dbf file and the dbf and its various codes are used based on the program's "needs".

Comment: It is a memo basically.

Comment: Aha. Then use memo nocptrans (or reset table's codepage or set it to 1252 - do Home()+'tools\cpzero\cpzero' with yourTable [, 1252]). OTOH why would you keep prg code in a memo? You simply store the compiled version instead (again memo nocptrans, else it translates based on table's codepage).

Comment: what do you mean :) You wouldn't add anything to cpzero.prg.